# Apply same text size to two different div's

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, text

I have got three different divs. 
Their font-size is generated by [jQuery bigtext](https://github.com/DanielHoffmann/jquery-bigtext/).

How can I achieve to scale all the three font-sizes dynamically 
but for each the same font-size ?
So the smallest possible font-size will be applied to all the three div's.
The result will be the same font-size for the three div's.

My current code works. But all the text have different font-sizes and are placed on the same page. That does not look very good.

My implementation of bigtext:

```
$(function() {
            $(window).on('resize', function() {
                  $(".competencesText").bigText({
                    horizontalAlign: "left",
                    verticalAlign: "top", 
                    textAlign: "left"
                  });
                  $(".competencesTextHeader").bigText({
                    horizontalAlign: "left",
                    verticalAlign: "top", 
                    textAlign: "left",
                  });
            });
                $(window).trigger('resize');    
            });
```

HTML

```
<div class="ThirdSectionTextArea">

              <div class="ThirdSectionTextAreaCell ThirdSectionTextAreaCell1">
              </div>
              <div class="ThirdSectionTextAreaCell ThirdSectionTextAreaCell2">
                  <div class="Row Row1 uppercase">
                      <div class="cell cell1">
                          <span class="competencesTextHeader">
                            Headline 
                          </span>
                      </div>
                       <div class="cell cell2">
                           <span class="competencesTextHeader">
                                Headline
                           </span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="cell cell3">
                          <span class="competencesTextHeader">
                                Headline
                          </span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row Row2">
                      <div class="cell cell1">
                           <table class="layoutTable"><tr><td class="centerDiv">
                               <div class="h_line">
                               </div>
                           </td></tr></table>
                      </div>
                       <div class="cell cell2">
                            <table class="layoutTable"><tr><td class="centerDiv">
                               <div class="h_line">
                               </div>
                           </td></tr></table>
                      </div>
                       <div class="cell cell3">
                            <table class="layoutTable"><tr><td class="centerDiv">
                               <div class="h_line">
                               </div>
                           </td></tr></table>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row Row3">
                      <div class="cell cell1">
                          <span class="competencesText">
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                          </span>
                      </div>
                       <div class="cell cell2">
                           <span class="competencesText">
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                           </span>
                      </div>
                       <div class="cell cell3">
                           <span class="competencesText">
                             Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
                           </span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
              <div class="ThirdSectionTextAreaCell ThirdSectionTextAreaCell3">
              </div>

          </div>
```

until now, all the three div's I am talking about are set to the class "competencesText". 
Do I have to implement three different functions for each or is there another possibility to get all the fonts to the same size?

Comment: You are not saying if what you are doing works or not and which is the problem you are experiencing. Your HTML posted here would also help.

Comment: @Franco : I have updatet my post.

Comment: Your function is set inside the 'on resize ' event so they don't look good when you load the site, but what happen when you resize the browser?

Comment: The resize function is even called when the page loads for the first time. When I resize the browser the function gets called too and resizes the text. But each text field in another size